# custom list view consisting of web view is not responding to the onitemclicklistener

Tags: android, listview, webview, onitemclicklistener

My application  consists of of custom listview  which has couple of textview's and a webview . The application does not respond to onitemclicklistener.I am not able to focus on the list itself. I'm using web view to display an image from the URL.
any help will be greatly appreciated

thanks in advance,
_/|_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414) link,It turns out
that list item click events will never be received for list items with
views that can either handle click events or can gain focus.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `focusable` and `clickable` to false, but it does not work if you set them to `false` in the `xml` like so:

```
 android:clickable="false"
 android:focusable="false"
```

instead you need to do it in code with a

```
myWebViewInAListView.setFocusable(false);
```